# Extracting specific internal nodes from an xml file and construct a dataframe in r

Tags: r, xml-parsing

I have an xml file that I want to extract specific nodes from in R using `xmlToDataFrame` from the `XML` package. I can get the function to extract data from individual nodes. ex:

```
xml <- xmlParse("file.xml")

df <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xml, "//lat"))
```

However I was wondering if its possible to extract multiple nodes at the same time? Specifically I am looking to make a five column dataframe extracting data from nodes: `//nucleotides`,`//lat`,`//lon`,`//bin_uri`,`//record_id` from the xml.

The structure of the xml file is as follows (just one `record_id` but there are many in the file that I need to extract):

```
    <record>
      <record_id>634750</record_id>
      <processid>CCSMA054-07</processid>
      <bin_uri>AAG2098</bin_uri>
      <collection_event>
        <collectors>Arctic Ecology</collectors>
          <coordinates>
            <lat>58.805</lat>
            <lon>-94.214</lon>
          </coordinates>
        <country>Canada</country>
        <province>Manitoba</province>
      </collection_event>
      <sequences>
       <sequence>
         <sequenceID>3336699</sequenceID>
         <markercode>COI-5P</markercode>
         <genbank_accession>HQ938393</genbank_accession>
         <nucleotides>CTCAGAGTTCTCACCTGGC</nucleotides>
       </sequence>
      </sequences>
    </record>
```

Comment: I ended getting an error:  Error in xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(xml, ii)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'doc' in selecting a method for function 'xmlToDataFrame': Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got another error:  Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: I will post an example of the xml data files I am using http://www.boldsystems.org/index.php/API_Public/combined?taxon=Brachipoda&geo=Canada&format=xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider simply running various [xpath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) expressions using `xpathSApply()` and then bind all together into a data frame:

```
library(XML)

doc<-xmlParse("D:/Freelance Work/Scripts/BoldXML.xml")

record_id <- xpathSApply(doc, "//record/record_id", xmlValue)
bin_uri <- xpathSApply(doc, "//record/bin_uri", xmlValue)
lat <- xpathSApply(doc, "//record/collection_event/coordinates/lat", xmlValue)
lon <- xpathSApply(doc, "//record/collection_event/coordinates/lon", xmlValue)
nucleotides <- xpathSApply(doc, "//record/sequences/sequence/nucleotides", xmlValue)

df <- data.frame(record_id = unlist(record_id), 
                 bin_uri = unlist(bin_uri),                  
                 lat = unlist(lat),
                 lng = unlist(lon),
                 nucleotides = unlist(nucleotides))
```

---

Alternatively, you can simplify your raw XML using [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt), the special-purpose language that restructures/re-designs XML files. While R does not have a universal XSLT package, practically all general purpose languages (C#, Java, PHP, Perl, Python, VB) maintain XSLT libraries which you can even call scripts from R with [system()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html). Even more, command line programs such as Windows' PowerShell and Linux's Bash can run XSLT.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl or .xslt)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="record_id"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="bin_uri"/>     
      <xsl:copy-of select="collection_event/coordinates/lat"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="collection_event/coordinates/lon"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="sequences/sequence/nucleotides"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**XML** *(after transformation)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <record>
    <record_id>634750</record_id>
    <bin_uri>AAG2098</bin_uri>
    <lat>58.805</lat>
    <lon>-94.214</lon>
    <nucleotides>CTCAGAGTTCTCACCTGGC</nucleotides>
  </record>
</root>
```

**R** Script:

```
result <- system('..some command line call to an external script that 
                  parses original xml and above xslt script and transforms
                  former with the latter..', intern = TRUE)

doc <- xmlParse("C:/Path/To/Transformed/XML.xml")
df <- xmlToDataFrame(getNodeSet(doc, "//record"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it to work using the first option with xpathSApply().

Comment: Great! Please accept to confirm resolution. Be careful though for missing XML values as the list lengths may differ and cannot align to dataframe columns.

Comment: the xslt solution worked well for me too.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer, `getNodeSet` with an xpath is another way to quickly get the values you want. If each xpath had one node you could use:

```
library(XML)

doc <- xmlParse("D:/Freelance Work/Scripts/BoldXML.xml")

record_id <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//record/record_id"))
bin_uri   <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//record/bin_uri"))
lat       <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//record/collection_event/coordinates/lat"))
lon       <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//record/collection_event/coordinates/lon"))
ntides    <- xmlValue(getNodeSet(doc, "//record/sequences/sequence/nucleotides"))
```